# Client Connect sequence not working in Paho MQTT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I have a pseudo-sensor from which I have to get data and use the Paho MQTT library to prepare to send MQTT messages to AWS.

I implemented the following code for sending the data:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import os
import socket
import ssl
from time import sleep
from random import uniform
from psuedoSensor import PseudoSensor

connflag = False

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global connflag
    connflag = True
    print("Connection returned result: " + str(rc) )

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Connected with status: {0}".format(response_code))


mqttc = paho.Client()
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message


awshost = "XXXXXXXXXXX.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
awsport = 8883
clientId = "Project_1"
thingName = "Project_1"
caPath = "C:/Project 1/aws-iot-rootCA.crt"
certPath = "C:Project 1/cert.pem.crt"
keyPath = "C:Project 1/privkey.pem"

mqttc.tls_set(caPath, certPath, keyPath, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)

mqttc.connect(awshost, awsport, keepalive=60)

mqttc.loop_start()

while 1==1:
    sleep(0.5)
    if connflag == True:
        for i in range(30):
            ps = PseudoSensor()
            h,t = ps.generate_values()
            mqttc.publish("temperature", t, qos=1)
            print("msg sent: temperature " + "%.2f" % t )
            mqttc.publish("humidity", h, qos=1)
            print("msg sent: humidity " + "%.2f" % h )

    else:
        print("waiting for connection...")
```

I understand that `mqttc.on_connect = on_connect` isn't working, i.e., not setting the connflag as "True" because I am getting an output as "waiting for connection", but I don't know why.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I suggest you also add an `on_dissconnect` and `on_log` callback to try and gather some more information. Also how long have you left it after starting? How many `waiting for connection` messages are you seeing?

Comment: In addition to the above check that your `crt` and `pem` are loading (my guess is that changing `"C:Project 1/c..."` to `"C:/Project 1/c..."` might help because, as it stands, the paths are relative to the working folder).

Comment: @Brits Yes this solved it. I didn't have a proper understanding of how to work python from the command line and found a way to open cmd from the current path. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using windows, make sure you have the port 8883 open in your firewall. If you cannot open the port, then use 443 but then you have to modify your code in order to change the alpn to `x-amzn-mqtt-ca`

Here is a blog post treating that aspect:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/how-to-implement-mqtt-with-tls-client-authentication-on-port-443-from-client-devices-python/

Comment: Windows doesn't, to my knowledge, block outgoing traffic by default. So, while it's possible that something is restricting outgoing traffic, taking a look at the logs is probably a good first step (there are many other potential issues).

Comment: I think this wasn't an issue, as @Brits suggests. The issue were the relative paths. Thanks for the response though!